# Erro na chamada de modal com bootstrap 4 e jquery com o id= "#"

Tags: html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Então pessoal, criei um modal da seguinte forma:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="#siteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Softwares</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span>&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>...</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">CERTO</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Porém quando faço a seguinte chamada:

```
<a href="#" class="card-link mb-1  txt btn btn-outline-dark" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#siteModal">SAIBA MAIS</a>
```

O modal não é chamado, pois está dando conflito com o layout estilo one-page, porque o mesmo tá utilizando o id="#" que é igual ao href do link que chamará o modal.
Como faço para que apareça o modal? Alguma sugestão? Pois quando clico no botão ele joga para o início do site, obedecendo o id="#"

Comment: Não tem como trocar esse href por outra coisa?

Comment: Troque o # por `javascript:void(0)`

Answer (score 2):

O problema não é o `href`, ele não entra em conflito. O problema do seu código é que no modal o `id` está com `#`.

Removendo não terá problemas. Segue o código corrigido abaixo:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="siteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Softwares</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span>&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>...</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">CERTO</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ou caso queira por algum motivo manter o `#` no id do modal. Basta alterar o código do link para o seguinte:

```
<a href="#asd" class="card-link mb-1  txt btn btn-outline-dark" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#\#siteModal">SAIBA MAIS</a>
```

Comment: Copiei a chamada que colocou, o erro persistiu, mesmo colocando o id do modal no `href`. Retirei a cerquilha `#` de todos os componentes que não precisavam e nada. Alguma outra ideia ou alternativa para chamada?

Answer (score 0):

**Você também pode abrir o modal**

1. colocando como valor do atributo href da tag `a` o valor `#siteModal`
2. Retirando o jogo da velha (cerquilha ou octothorpe) `#` do id do modal

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="modal fade" id="siteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Softwares</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span>&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>...</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">CERTO</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<a href="#siteModal" class="card-link mb-1  txt btn btn-outline-dark" data-toggle="modal" data-target="">SAIBA MAIS</a>
```

Comment: Retirei a cerquilha `#` do id  no modal e coloquei o id no `href` do link `a` e nada. Alguma outra ideia? Obrigado desde já.

Comment: @BrenoFroes, se tem ids iguais no código então tem que mudar um deles.  Você diz que está dando conflito com o layout estilo one-page, pode mostar esse trecho de código que tem o mesmo id?